# How to make persistent installation with Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there a way to have a persistent installation on the machine you get when you launch a notebook from the Colaboratory Environment ?

There is such a mechanism with mybinder.org with a requirements.txt or setup.py that specify the different packages you want at the startup.
https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_files.html#requirements-txt-install-a-python-environment

I have tested a colab notebook with an installation procedure but I have to rerun a sequence of cells each time I want to work.
Try:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u5Y-92-b4rVcJjkUpPPa5xnuvKAHcnNa

Also how to define environment variables for once (at startup) ?
Do I have also to rerun their settings each time ?

Thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I install a library `jdc` permanently, by installing it in Google Drive.

```py
import os, sys
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/mnt')
nb_path = '/content/notebooks'
os.symlink('/content/mnt/My Drive/Colab Notebooks', nb_path)
sys.path.insert(0, nb_path)

# call this one time only
!pip install --target=$nb_path jdc
# later just import it
import jdc   # for %%add_to
```

And here's how to set environmental variables.

```
%env VAR1=value1
%env VAR2=value2
```

Put them in your first cell and run it.